# Copying memory to the flexible array member

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, flexible-array-member

I'm trying to write an allocation function for a struct with a flexible array member. I implemented it as follows:

```
int ns_request_character(char *char_out){
     //returns 0 on success, -1 on error
}

struct ns_fam{
    size_t size;
    char data[];
};

struct ns_fam * ns_allocate(size_t size){
    char data[size];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
        char char_out;
        if(ns_request_character(&char_out) == -1){
            return NULL;
        }
        data[i] = char_out;
    }
    struct ns_fam *ns_fam = malloc(sizeof(*ns_fam) + sizeof(char[size]));
    if(ns_fam){
        ns_fam->size = size;
        memcpy(ns_fam->data, data, sizeof(data));  // <-- ???
    }
    return ns_fam;
}
```

The thing I'm not sure about is copying the stack variable length array's memory to the flexible array member. I did it this way in order to avoid handling `free` of the structure in case `ns_request_character` returned `-1`.

Comment: That looks ok. It's fine. I think I'll vote it's unclear what you are asking - there is no question in your post. `to avoid handling free` - I think handling `free` will be less production / "safe" costly, for big `size` you have no way of error checking.

Comment: @KamilCuk By avoid handling free I meant to avoid allocation the `struct ns_fam` on the heap and in case of error I would have to deallocate it to avoid memory leak.

Comment: Flexible array members are a little special and somewhat similar to pointers. You can't gets its size with `sizeof` and its size isn't counted as part of the size of the structure. Other than that you can treat it like any other array, which means your copying to it is fine.

Comment: if `char data[size]` might cause a stack overflow then it's probably better to malloc first and then free if you have to. Also there's no need for `char_out`, you can just read directly into the destination